# Is a Prism module necessarily a separate project?

Tags: prism

Is a Prism module necessarily a separate project?

I saw some examples so far where all modules are separate projects,
and then some other examples where for example you have one main project
and in there you have module definitions, that is classes that implement the
IModule interface. Kinda confusing what a module exactly is. Actually I know what it is,
but how is it actually implemented. Is it always implemented as separate project or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not always implemented separately.  The idea of separating components of your MVVM solution is for a few reasons and can be for different concepts.

- Mix/Match - To allow (or just show) how interchangeable MVVM allows an entire solution to be you can build individual modules.  You can mix and match, either in development or even at runtime if you get deep into MVVM.
- Organization - Some people, myself included, like our Properties to be grouped together, the Member Variables to be together, etc. Whereas others like to have the variable immediately above the associated Property.  The former would likely also group his/her MVVM project into Views as a project, ViewModels as a separate.

So you may assume a project to be an indivual module, which is the Mix/Match.  Or you can have modules together in a few projects, some alone and some with multiple modules, and Mix/Match that way as well if appropriate.

Nothing says you have to.  Small project? Keep it simple.  Small project but want to learn? Go multiple projects.